# Send file to a different server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an upload url in my backend and i want to upload a file in another server.

My API view:

```
  class AssessmentFileUpload(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        tenant = request.user.tenant.id

        response = AssessmentFileUploadHelper(tenant).upload_file(request.FILES)
        response_text = json.loads(response.text)
        print(response_text)
        if response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
            return Response({"message": "success", "id": response_text.get('id')}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({"message": "failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My class which sends request data to the other serve's url:

```
class AssessmentFileUploadHelper:
    def __init__(self, tenant_id):
        self.tenant_id = tenant_id

    
    def upload_file(self, file):
        print("FILE IS", file)
        url = settings.ASSESSMENT_CONNECTION_SETTINGS["api_endpoint"] + "tenant/" + \
        str(self.tenant_id) + "/fileupload/"
        return RequestSender().send_request(url,None, file)

class RequestSender:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __get_authorized_header(self):
        usernamepassword = settings.ASSESSMENT_CONNECTION_SETTINGS["userid"] + ":" + settings.ASSESSMENT_CONNECTION_SETTINGS["password"]
        userAndPass = b64encode(usernamepassword.encode("utf-8")).decode("ascii")
        authorization = "Basic " + userAndPass
        headers = {'Authorization': authorization, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        return headers

    def send_request(self, url, data, files=None):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        response = requests.post(url,
                                 data=json_data,
                                 headers=self.__get_authorized_header(),
                                 files=files
                                 )
        return response
```

Now, the errors im getting is InMemoryUploadedFile is not json serilizaable . How to send request.FILES to that server ?

Comment: Can you write the output of `print(response.text)` ? The value seems not to be a valid json structure.

Comment: response is not there because it throws error

Comment: The same error that you mentioned ? How about value of `print(response)` ?

Comment: i will update my question

Comment: can you check now @cristian  . Here im trying to send files in request .The error im getting now is ValueError: Data must not be a string.

Comment: The error is not in response , im sending a file , not recieveing. Im sending a file in post request

Comment: Got it. Try seeing what is written in the `request` variable (post function).

Comment: @cristian output for FILE IS :FILE IS <MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 51335002_367250667191535_1373717097460269056_n.jpg.jpg.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>

Comment: Seems that is an image file.you cannot use it as a json. (you need a text file)

Comment: ok i was able to post now after sending as bytes

Comment: Great. I have updated my response. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neet to convert 'InMemoryUploadedFile' type to string:

```
str = request.FILES['file'].read().decode()
```